# What versions of native Android development does IBM MobileFirst 6.3 support?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm looking at developing a native Android app using MobileFirst 6.3 CLI but cannot find documentation anywhere on what versions of Android are supported by MobileFirst?

I wish my app to be able to run on Gingerbread.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobileFirst Platform supports the following Android OS versions for *native apps* (not to be confused with Hybrid apps:

- 2.x - 5.x

For Hybrid apps:

- 2.3.5 and above
- 3.x - *not supported*
- 4.x
- 5.x

Comment: Thanks!  not 2.3.6?  and this is for developing native Android in Android studio using MobileFirst CLI yes?

Comment: 2.3.5 and above in the 2.5 series. Both MobileFirst Studio and the MobileFirst CLI will generate an Android project for you. You can then open it in Android Studio or Eclipse.